# Creating Custom RWD theme not working

Tags: magento-1.9, custom, rwd-theme

I followed a lot of tutorials to create a custom RWD theme with Magento.
But when I'm finished, the website is  not the same as the original RWD theme.

The header with the profile tab is not displayed correctly.
It got no styling
I checked the console and there was nothing displayed.
It must show something like this.
[image]

But it shows this
[image]

I don't know if the CSS is loaded correctly
You could check Unilinxx.com if you want to see the result

Comment: Did you copy the rwd theme to a new directory with the name of your theme? It could be possible that you're missing the /skin directory for this?

Comment: No I just copied the rwd directory and renamed it to my own

Comment: In your instance merge css and js set it to no and flush cache after it.

Comment: could you give me step by step what I should do ?